# JSON and Nodemon Functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to output the string "translations" when `/translations` is called, but this is not displayed in the browser.

```
const http = Noderequire('http');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const  { url } = (req);
    console.log(url);

    if (url === '/ translations') {
        res.end ('translations');
    }

    res.end('Hi Chris, Welcome too Node!');
});
```

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What does this have to do with nodemon? Can your share the rest of the file/code for this? You also may have an extra space in '/ translations'.

Comment: Here is the remaining piece of code  below. Nodemon allows us to automatically restart the server when ever we update our application and hit save. I have also removed the extra space in '/translations'. and still is not working.

Comment: server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at ${hostname}:${port}`);
});

Comment: I removed the extra space and I am getting `translations` when querying `localhost:3000/translations`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in your `if` statement when checking for the url path. The below should work.

```
if (url === '/translations') {
    res.end ('translations');
}
```

Comment: I just cleared the extra space in the if statement and is still not working

Comment: if (url === '/translations') {
        res.end ('translations');
    }

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but remove `Node` from `const http = require('http');` Aside from these two changes, I have no problems with getting `'translations'` or `'Hi Chris, Welcome too Node!'` to be in the response